# How can I get all the features displayed on a map in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Is there a way I can get all the features from a OpenLayers Vector layer that are visible on the map?

For example what if the layer has 100 features, but at the zoom level I am at, at the moment I can only see 20 of these features.

Is there a way to programmatically get the visible features on the map?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OL2 solution, my answer from 2013:

Have a look at the `onScreen` method of OpenLayers:

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html#OpenLayers.Marker.onScreen

OL3 solution:

[Get all features from the Openlayers 3 viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785940/get-all-features-from-the-openlayers-3-viewport?rq=1)

Comment: Nice one! Didnt think to check the feature API, and just checked the layer API!

Thanks again

Comment: Just got a downvote on this: note this was anwered in 2013 so it may not work in 2018 ...