# Get all features from the Openlayers 3 viewport

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to find out all the features which are visible (viewport) on a layer in Openlayers 3.

I am able to find out a single feature if I add a click event to the map which is as follows. But I am not able to find all the features which are visible in the viewport. Could anyone help with this?

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
            function(feature, layer) {
                return feature;
            });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I propose that first you get the extent of the view :

```
var extent = yourMap.getView().calculateExtent(yourMmap.getSize());
```

then get all features within this extent :

```
yourVectorSource.forEachFeatureInExtent(extent, function(feature){
    // do something 
});
```

Comment: What if the feature is styled off? I mean, if the feature is filtered and not showing on the map? The yourVectorSource.forEachFeatureInExtent() will still return the feature by I wanted to know which are not rendered on the map... any way to know that?